# Forms in Scala play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Hello i am a beginner to scala play framework. I am unable to create form with two or more inputs. i googled it and found none in scala programming language. Kindly suggest me an idea regarding how to create multiple inputs in a form using scala. i did this

```
val form = Form (tuple
    (
"firstname"-> text,
"lastname" -> text
)
)  and to get the values val(fname,lname) = form.bindFromRequest.get
```

am i following correct way. Kindly suggest me any idea or resource to learn scala play framework . Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you by any chance importing scala.text? Removing it and adding the appropriate imports as below answer by @Matt Robots should solve your problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a complete (but simple) form example for Play 2.1.1. Including the view, controller and routes file. I suspect you were [missing imports](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaForms) and / or an [implicit request](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaActions). Both of which would be understandable!

The controller (Application.scala):

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

object Application extends Controller {
  val form = Form(
    tuple(
      "firstname" -> text,
      "lastname" -> text
    )
  )

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

  def submit = Action { implicit request =>
    val (fname, lname) = form.bindFromRequest.get
    Ok("Hi %s %s".format(fname, lname))
  }
}
```

The view (index.scala.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" autocomplete="on">
      First name:<input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
POST    /                           controllers.Application.submit
```

*NB: The name attributes in your HTML view must match the string literals in your controller form.*

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a way to then validate this type of form (it a tuple rather than a case class), and pass the structure back to the template when it fails validation?

Comment: Yes! It's described in the [Play 2.x documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms) under 'Defining constraints'. For example: `"firstname" -> nonEmptyText`.

Comment: How can I then pass that into a template? Whenever I try the template complains that Form must have a generic type, but in the case shown for a tuple, id doesn't!?

Comment: when i add third inputbox it says, [NoSuchElementException: None.get], can you help me

Comment: `val (fname, lname) = form.bindFromRequest.get` fails for me with type matching error. what might cause that? `val name = form.bindFromRequest.get` works OK tho

Comment: Is this suitable for Play 2.5.x as well?

Answer (score 0):

Play documentation is the best way to learn about forms 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaForms if you want more then, please have a look at play-example-form project.

http://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-example-form This activator example project on forms explains everything about forms.

1) It explains forms and data binding, validation in the play controller.

2) It explains about `Optional parameters` in the forms.

3) It explains about complex forms with nested objects for example

```
     case class Student(name: String, age: Int, gender: Optional[Char] = None, 
                                                address: Address, other: OtherStuff)
```

The above case class depends on Address, OtherStuff and 
notice that the gender is optional. The example project explains how to deal with such complex object dependencies.

Please download activator from here http://typesafe.com/get-started . then, start the activator in browser UI mode using the command `activator ui` and type play-example-form in the search to download it. After downloading go to the project root folder and type `activator eclipse` in case you use eclipse or `activator gen-idea` in case you Intellij Idea.